# Interfacing AutoCAD plugin with external program

Tags: c#, python, com, interop, autocad

I'm making a python app to automate some tasks in AutoCAD (drawing specific shapes in specific layers and checking the location of some circles).

For the first part, drawing things, it was easy to use the AutoCAD Interop library, as you could easily put objects in the active document without doing anything on AutoCAD, not even loading any plugin. However i don't find any way of using that same library to check the properties of objects in the document.

What I need is a function that, when passed as argument the layer name, returns a list of the centers of every circle in that layer.

Now, it would be easy to do just by loading a plugin. But i need that info passed to a python program (that loads the AutoCAD Interop library through pythonnet) and i dont know how to do it.

So, summarizing, I need to:

- Learn how to use the AutoCAD Interop library to retrieve drawing's info.

or

- Interface an AutoCAD plugin with an external app writen in python.

Is it possible what i intend to do? What would be the best approach?

Comment: You need to build a selection set that is filtered to select just the circles on the layers in question. Then you iterate the selection set and examine each circle and obtain the center point.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use AutoCAD without Interop:

1. You can host the WCF services in AutoCAD and interact with them. I haven't free sample, sorry (only my private solutions, not for publishing). WCF services can be hosted in the `acad.exe` or `accoreconsole.exe` (excepting `accoreconsole.exe` 2016).
2. You can host PowerShell in AutoCAD and interact with it also. The sample of this way I published [here](https://bitbucket.org/Andrey-Bushman/cad-via-powershell/wiki/Home).

I use these ways for different cases.

Answer (score 0):

About this:
"Interface an AutoCAD plugin with an external app written in python"

From what I understand the plugin is only accessible through the open AutoCAD Application, so in order to interface with the plugin your app will have to interface with AutoCAD.

I don't know if this is possible with Python, but using the AutoCAD interop with C# you can do this:

```
public void SendCommand(string command, params object[] args)
{
    AcadApplication app = GetActiveApp();
    AcadDocument acDoc = app.ActiveDocument;

    // Without arguments
    acDoc.SendCommand("command");

    // With arguments
    acDoc.SendCommand("command args[2], args[1], args[2]");
}
```

So you would be able to call your plugin like this:

```
acDoc.SendCommand("yourPluginCommandName layerName");
```